# Oracle Driver not found? Classpath is set, JAR/JDBC file file is compatible

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

IMPORTANT:
I am not using any 3rd party apps, just java 1.8 (32-bit), Oracle 10G express edition, notepad, and Command prompt.

I am facing an error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
        at OracleCon.main(OracleCon.java:5)
```

My OracleCon.java file:

```java
import java.sql.*;
public class OracleCon{
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");    //exception is here
            //other part of code
        }  catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have done following stuff:

1. Set JAVA_HOME as path in system environment variable.
2. Removed oracle path for java in system: `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`
3. Copied `ojdbc14` and `ojdbc14_g` ".jar" file found at `C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib`, pasted at `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\ext`
4. Compiled and executed, failed!
5. Set CLASSPATH as ojdbc/jar file in jre lib folder.
6. Compiled and executed, failed!
7. Copied those ojdbc/jar files and pasted those in my folder where this `OracleCon.java` file is located in.
8. Compiled and excuted, and failed!
9. Tried installing those ojdbc/jar files from internet (javatpoint).
10. Uninstalled and reinstalled java (jdk and jre), and oracle.
11. Downloaded `ojdbc8.jar`, copied-pasted same in different folders!

Note: I had closed and re-opened Command Prompt after each step!

Comment: I'm not sure what `ojdbc14` and `ojdbc14_g` are, but the JDBC driver files will have a `.jar` suffix, so they are not it. You will need to be much more explicit about what you did: "Set classpath as ojdbc file in jre lib folder" tells us nothing.

Comment: A JDBC driver is just a jar. You need to put it in the classpath, just like you would for any other library.

Comment: Yes @tgdavies those are the jar files

Comment: @Olivier I had copied-pasted those jar file in `jre/lib/ext`, that didn't work so used "Set classpath" method

Comment: What exact `java` command line did you use at step 5? Please answer by editing your question rather than in a comment.

Comment: @tgdavies java OracleCon, I had compiled OracleCon.java file before it. I use Windows 11 laptop

Comment: So what did you do to set the classpath?

Comment: Set claspath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\ext\ojdbc14.jar;.;

Comment: "claspath" is misspelled.

Comment: Sorry thats my bad! I misspelled it here

Comment: Exact command is: `Set classpath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\ext\ojdbc14.jar;.;`

Comment: Incorrect.  Should be `CLASSPATH`.

Comment: @StephenC that didn't work too! My command `set CLASSPATH = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\lib\ext\ojdbc14.jar;.;`

Comment: Well ... there are other problems.  I'm not 100% familiar with Windows, but shouldn't the value be quoted?  And the final `;` should not be there.

Comment: And I am not convinced that `ojdbc14.jar` is the correct driver JAR for Java 8.  According to https://www.oracle.com/au/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html you should be using `ojdbc8.jar`.   (ojdbc14 is the JAR for Java 1.4 ...)

Comment: That doesn't work too! I tried putting it in quotes too! Removed that `;` and `.;` as 2 different commands with those

Comment: @StephenC I tried downloading ojdbc8.jar file and setting it as classpath. But it doen't work!

Comment: You really shouldn't put stuff in `lib/ext`, that extension mechanism is even removed in more recent Java versions.

Comment: But I am using `java 1.8 (32-bit)`